# The acces token of the azure web app obtained through AadTokenProvider will expire in one hour and no new token will be obtained

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, access-token, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I get the access token with the following code.

```
protected async getAccessToken(): Promise<string> {  
         return await this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory
             .getTokenProvider()
             .then((tokenProvider: AadTokenProvider): Promise<string> => {
                 return tokenProvider.getToken(Config.resourceEndpoint, false);
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.error("getAccessToken", error);
                 return null;
             });
     }
```

The access token obtained every time is the same, but this token will expire in one hour, which will cause me to be unable to access the webapi on the azure web app. How can I solve this problem? Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Is this in front-end code? And you get the error in log after the hour?

Comment: It's the react code in SPFx web part. The azure app api will return 401 error after token expired.

Comment: Usually MSAL (if that is used here) should refresh the token automatically through implicit flow (hidden iframe). So it would return the same token for about 55 minutes and then get a new token and return that. Are you always asking for a new token from this?

Comment: It used adal.js in AadTokenProvider. After 55 minutes, an old token is returned instead of a new token.

Comment: When I implemented it, I referred to the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad#access-an-api-secured-with-azure-ad-from-sharepoint-framework-solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you call `tokenProvider.getToken(Config.resourceEndpoint, false)` each time, it always gives you working access token, i.e., it internally refreshes token after an hour/whenever it expires and give you back. You don't have to take care of that in your code.

Comment: The official document also said the same, but I did not get a new token.

Comment: When I implemented it, I referred to the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad#access-an-api-secured-with-azure-ad-from-sharepoint-framework-solutions

Comment: It is recommended to use MSAL libraries written by protocol domain experts who follow a Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) methodology. ( https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)